# Selecting rows by applying search function on column data, Pandas, iPython

Tags: pandas, ipython

At the moment I can do this:

```
def my_search_function(text):
    return 'x' in text

df = pandas.DataFrame(mydata)

df['search'] = df['text'].apply(lambda text: my_search_function(text))
df[df['search']==True].sort('search', ascending=False)
```

and get results but I guess there should be a better way to group or select rows by function without creating new column for it?

More precicely:

```
search_num = 111
df['search'] = df['text'].apply(lambda text: list2string(find_number(string2list(text), search_num)))
df[df['search']!=''].sort('search', ascending=False)
```

Comment: Are you literally trying to see if any rows in your `text` column contains a string?

Comment: No, its more complicated thing. Just simplified example above.

Comment: Could you be more specific, I posted an answer that solves your question but it depends massively on what you are trying to achieve and the data

Comment: Ok, added more information

Comment: can you post some real sample data as `str.contains` may still work

Comment: I will get back on this tomorrow with example data and rest of the code, so it is easier. I don't think contains will work with it, because I need to calculate values from the string. It is not similar to plain string search...

Comment: So, I'm applying this function to my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380268/matching-the-sum-of-values-on-string/21380819#21380819

Sample data on data frame row col is: "70 58 81 909 70 215 70 1022 580 930 898".

Actually when I was thinking it more, making search result on own column is good idea after all. But I'm still interested to find out just total count of rows when searching nearby combinations, that produce 285 on text column.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a better method than using apply in this case